# Prompt in terminal prints out before finishing print statements for forks()

Tags: c, fork

I'm very new to fork() processes and in the given code below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main()
{
int i;
int n = 4;
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
   fork();
printf("hello\n");
return 0;
}
```

prints out something like

```
cse [prompt] ./Program1
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
cse [prompt] hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
```

Why exactly does the prompt print out again before finishing printing all the hellos? It doesn't really make sense to me.

Comment: The shell only waits for the first process to finish before printing the prompt. It doesn't track the child processes created by your code so those may still be running when the first process terminates. You need to add `wait` calls into your code if you want it to wait for all child processes to complete.

Comment: Note that your code is a mini-fork bomb. Every child process is also calling `fork` and so are their children and so on. Not sure if that is your intention.

Comment: Probably it would be energy better spent to learn pthreads. fork() is kind of archaic and, as we can tell from this, it has one of the most brittle APIs ever designed. It is mostly used for programmer poser syndrome, rather than for an actual need to create a new, identical process as the current one. Most of the time, threads is the correct solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

save each PID returned by FORK().

Then use the function `waitpid()` for each sub process, so the main process does not exit until all the sub processes (the child processes) have exited.